# Building a pattern to extract data out of a string

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have strings of the form:

```
"abc" 1 2 1 13 
"efgh" 2 5
```

Basically, a string in quotes followed by numbers separated by whitespace characters.
I need to extract the string and the numbers out of the line.

So for eg., for the first line, I'd want

- `abc` to be stored in a `String` variable (i.e. without the quotations) and
- an array of `int` to store `[1,2,1,13]`.

I tried to create a pattern that'd do this, but I'm a little confused.

```
Pattern P = Pattern.compile("\A\".+\"(\s\d+)+");
```

Not sure how to proceed now. I realized that with this pattern I'd kinda be extracting the whole line out? Perhaps multiple patterns would help?

```
Pattern P1 = Pattern.compile("\A\".+\"");
Pattern P2 = Pattern.compile("(\s\d+)+");
```

Again, not very sure how to get the string and ints out of the line though. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that the string part will not contain any numeric entry?

Comment: Why don't you just split on space?

Comment: Yes, the string part won't contain any numbers.

Comment: Yeah, I could split on space, but how would I get rid of the quotation marks?

Comment: You're on the way. Tip: I use [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) to test my `RegEx`es

Comment: Do you actually need all these features in Pattern Class? You can just employ the StringTokenizer to tokenize on " and spaces. You can make an array of all the tokens after the string token.
Posted in the answer section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather just split the string on space, rather than building complex regex, and use it with `Pattern` and `Matcher` class.

Something like this: -

```
String str = "\"abc\" 1 2 1 13 ";
String[] arrr = str.split("\\s");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrr));
```

**OUTPUT: -**

```
["abc", 1, 2, 1, 13]
```

Shows your intent much clearer, that what you want to do.

Then, you can get the `string` and `integer` parts from your string array. You would need to do a `Integer.parseInt()` on integer elements.

---

If your string may contain spaces in it, then in that case, you would need a `Regex`. Better one would be the one in `@m.buettner's` [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13286675/1679863)

Comment: Ok. The whitespace split makes a lot more sense than building a long regex. Can you confirm if my Pattern P1 is good for getting the string out of the quotes?

Comment: @krandiash.. Yeah it will work in your example. Did you try it?

Comment: No, I haven't yet. Was a little confused about the regex thing. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @krandiash.. Then you can try it. But IMHO, Regex is more suitable for more complex matching rather than this. If you really want to learn Regex, find complex problems on it.

Comment: Note that while this is really nice and simple, it will cause problems if your strings may contain spaces, too. (I believe that's what you are referring to in your last comment, @RohitJain)

Comment: @m.buettner.. Oh. didn't actually considered that. But yeah, there comes the need to `Regex`. Because, you would need some `look-ahead` and `look-behind` in case of `split`. So, now, Regex would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Use capturing groups to get both parts in one go, then split the numbers at spaces.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"\\s*([\\d\\s]*)");

Matcher m = pattern .matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    String str = m.group(1);
    String[] numbers = m.group(2).split("\\s");
    // process both of them       
}
```

Each set of parentheses in the regex will later correspond to one `group` (counting opening parentheses from left to right, starting at `1`).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this it will separate both String and int also

```
        String s = "\"abc\" 1 2 1 13 ";

        s = s.replace("\"", "");
        String sarray[] = s.split(" ");

        int i[] = new int[10];
        String si[] = new String[10];
        int siflag = 0;
        int iflag = 0;
        for (String st : sarray) {
            try {
                int ii = Integer.parseInt(st)
                i[iflag++] = ii;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                si[siflag++] = st;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Quite a generic solution., but you should rather use `int ii = Integer.parseInt(st)`, in your try block.

Answer (score 0):

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str,"\" ");
String token = null;
String strComponent = null;
int num[] = new int[10]; // can change length dynamically by using ArrayList
int i = 0;
int numTemp = -1;
while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
    token = st.nextToken();

    try{
        numTemp  = Integer.parseInt(token);
        num[i++] = numTemp ;
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
        strComponent = token.toString();
    }
```